# Issues with avg

Tags: windows-7, windows, anti-virus, malware, avg-antivirus

*I have windows 7 64 bit, avg internet security 2013, and malwarebytes pro. I don't know if i should ask it here or on security.SO, feel free to migrate it if you feel it does not belong here. I'll use the term malware, not virus, and lets not go through the discussion of having 2 anti virus on 1 pc, MWB is not a real time antivirus, I have another question about that subject, you can discuss it there*

Today, i scanned my pc using avg, got 55 malware, most of them are rootkits, avg told me to restart my pc, I did, the number was reduced to 35.

I scanned with MWB, got only 1 malware, removed it, MWB didn't detect anything else. I scanned with microsoft anti rootkit tool, and MWB rootkit removal tool got nothing.

I went to safe mode, opened AVG as adminstrator and scanned, in safe mode, avg scanner is like a command prompt you know, and I got this error for many files

[image]

- File locked! that drove me crazy, so do the anti virus scan the
  entire pc or only some files that are not locked? it makes no sense

I'm not done yet, i had enough with safe mode, decided to do an avg scan on the pc, remember the last time i scanned, i had 35 virus, when i rescaned i got 47!

I'm not done yet, i knew either, avg or MWB is lying to me, and it didn't make any sense to me that after restarting m pc, avg is still detecting the same number of malware if not more.

On my PC, there are no hidden files, for example, avg told me that

`"";"IRP hook, \FileSystem\Ntfs IRP_MJ_SHUTDOWN -> spaq.sys +0x3FB68, C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\spaq.sys";"Infected"`

- So i was curious to check that file, `Drivers` folder is full of
  `.sys files` but there's nothing called `spaq.sys`! Really? in fact
  most of the results `spaq.sys` that doesn't exist. How so?

AVG is only giving 1 details, `avg anti rootkit detected`spaq.sys`, that's not good enough for me, especially that i have 2 of the best anti rootkits installed. And how come no rootkit is removed after i restart? instead they increase.

**Initial issue solved**

I managed to remove the rootkits, by using [Kaspersky Anti-rootkit utility TDSSKiller](http://support.kaspersky.com/5350), i had 27 rootkits and they have different names, so Avg gave me wrong numbers and wrong names and was unable to remove them, after removing the rootkit using TDSSKiller, i scanned with avg and found nothing.

But I'll leave the question open, i still have no answer to the first question, why did i get `locked file` error? And therefore does the antivirus scan every single file on the system or does it skip the locked files?

Comment: OK, a few things: 1) Do not try to scan a potentially infected system while running it. Shut it down, boot from something else, then scan from that other booted OS. 2) Where did you get AVG? The legal site (where there is a free download) or an alternative site.  3) Warning: Some malware claims to the anti-virus but is not (partially to add to point 2. Partially to prevent you from downloading something 'helpful').  4) Please read this post: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc/157533

Comment: @Hennes 1) ill try to connect my laptop to another laptop and scan it 2) i got it from the official site avg.com 3) could you please give an example or more explanation? 4) thanks for the link sir :)

Comment: If AVG is saying a System file is infected your system is either so corrupt you should simply reinstall or its a false positive.  My honest viewpoint is that AVG has some serious problems, I have never trusted it, and suggest MSE instead.  It's very likely AVG is detecting false positives

Comment: You won't be able to see Spaq.sys if it IS a rootkit, since that's the point of a rootkit.

Comment: Anyway an example of fake security software is " Internet Security 2013"

Comment: Spaq.sys appears to be part of a package malicious package that infects your system volume you will NOT be able to remove it unless another system is but removal of it likely will corrupt your windows installation

Comment: @Ramhound please read my edit, and yes i'm seriously looking for avg alternatives, mse might not be the best http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-3667_7-57564385/microsoft-bombs-another-security-test/

Comment: You can post all the reviews you want but MSE has never failed to prevent an infection.  AVG has corrupted my emails, failed to detect the most basic infection I threw at it, and clearly failed you.  The locked file is easy NTFS can lock files your infection did this at the file system level.

Comment: @Ramhound `Spaq.sys is part of a package malicious package that infects your system volume you will NOT be able to remove it unless another system is but removal of it likely will corrupt your windows installation` seriously? i hope it's not that bad! wow!

Comment: @Fischer if you were able to remove what was detected you likely disabled anything else that exists but I would perform a reinstall 24 malicious files is a lot.  Be sure to post an answer otherwise people can't vote on it.

Comment: I found this http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/364365/trojan-win32-infection-as-smssexe-servicesexe/ when I searched for the file on my phone but I would run the tool just incase

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the link sir, i'll check it and install mse instead of avg and if that doesn't fix it i'll reinstall windows, its my last option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to remove the rootkits, by using [Kaspersky Anti-rootkit utility TDSSKiller](http://support.kaspersky.com/5350), i had 27 rootkits and they have different names, so Avg gave me wrong numbers and wrong names and was unable to remove them, after removing the rootkit using TDSSKiller, i scanned with avg and found nothing.